# Expect "Object" to receive message not working as expected

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, testing, rspec

I have this spec:

```
it 'makes a request to google if redis is empty' do
  fetch_cfm_data

  expect(GoogleCalendarApi::V1::Client).to receive(:get_cfm)
end
```

I've debugged the messages being called during this process of my test and `GoogleCalendarApi::V1::Client.get_cfm` is certainly being called because I can pry inside of that method during the test run. Why does my test return this failure?

```
Failure/Error: expect(GoogleCalendarApi::V1::Client).to receive(:get_cfm)

       (GoogleCalendarApi::V1::Client (class)).get_cfm(*(any args))
           expected: 1 time with any arguments
           received: 0 times with any arguments
```

Comment: Move your action (fetch_cfm_data) to after the expect line,

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to first set expectations, and then call the method under test:

```
  expect(GoogleCalendarApi::V1::Client).to receive(:get_cfm)
  fetch_cfm_data
```

See more in [`rspec-mocks` docs](https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-mocks/v/3-8/docs/basics/expecting-messages).

Comment: Or you can use a `spy` and use `expect(spy).to have_received(message)` [Spies](https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-mocks/docs/basics/spies)